# how to retain expand/collapse state in jqgrid grouping?

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have implemented a jqgrid in grouping method. By default I have kept the groups collapsed using `groupCollapse:true` parameter of jqgrid. My grid works well but When I expand the group and sort a column, the whole grid is reloaded and the expanded state of the column is not retained. How can I retain the expanded state while sorting?

Comment: Please write always which **version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and from which **fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). Your requirements could be easy realized in "free jqGrid", which I develop. It allows to use `groupCollapse` as callback function, which returns Boolean. In combination with `onClickGroup` callback or `jqGridGroupingClickGroup` event one can easy persist the grouping state.

Comment: @Oleg I used the Guriddo jqGrid JS, the free non-commercial version 5.2.1. Already I was referring your posts on stackoverflows but I am not aware that you have your own implementation of jqgrid. I am ready to use your implementation if that can help me to maintain the expand/collapse state when sorted. Please give me some sample code so that I can incorporate the logic to my grid.

Comment: Guriddo jqGrid JS 5.2.1 is **commercial** product! You can open `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` file in text editor and see `License: http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334` at the beginning comment. The corresponding link http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334 shows the prices of the product. [The post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438) announced changing the name and making the product commercial. MIT license allows to make fork of the product at any time and I made the fork of jqGrid 4.7 (the last version having MIT licence and be used for free) at the end of 2014. Free jqGrid 4.15.2 is the current ver.

Comment: I created the demo https://jsfiddle.net/92da8xhq/, which demonstrates what one can do. See **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: @Oleg, I have seen the fiddle above and that is great! :) thank you so much! Next I incorporate your solution to my implementation here and accept your answer. By the way I need some clarification, on the licensing above,  [http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334] atop the page it is stated that _If you want to use this product for a personal, school or non-profit project, then you can use it for free under the Creative Commons Attribution-Non-Commercial 3.0 License._ So I downloaded it and using it for my project. I didn't distribute it to someone or make money out of it. Isn't it legible?

Comment: I'm not an expert in juristic questions. You can read the license of Guriddo or ask somebody else. At the first look it seems that you din't broke the Guriddo license till now. In any way, the features, which I described you in my answer and which you need, exist only in "free jqGrid" fork and not in Guriddo. You can search in the code of [grid.grouping.js](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.grouping.js) for `groupCollapse` to see that Guriddo uses `groupCollapse` as Boolean only and it's not allow to use it as callback and to have different `groupCollapse` values for rows

Comment: @Oleg, in the fiddle above, in the code,`collapsedGroups: { "test2": true },` you have mentioned the "test2" group should be maintained as collapsed. But in my case , the data are generated dynamically by the server. I am not sure of how many groups will be there in the grid at any point of time. Also I am not sure of what value is going to be there in the grouped row (like, test1, test2, test3). Everything is from server and could change over time. In that case what shall I do? is the `collapsedGroups` option mandatory??? help me.

Comment: I wrote in my answer that one can use empty `collapsedGroups: { }` if one need to display all expanding groups at the initial load. The code included in my answer in an example the implementation which adds/removes properties during collapsing/expanding. If both "test2" and "test3" are collapsed then `collapsedGroups` contains `{ test2: true, test3: true }`. I used object properties instead of array to improve the performance.

Comment: I recommend you additionally to read [the page](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html), which is introduction on free jqGrid. After that it could be helpful to look through [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write always which **version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and from which **fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Your requirements could be easy realized in "free jqGrid", which I develop. It allows to use `groupCollapse` as callback function, which returns Boolean (see [the issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/82)). In combination with `onClickGroup` callback or `jqGridGroupingClickGroup` event one can easy persist the grouping state.

**UPDATED:** I created the demo https://jsfiddle.net/92da8xhq/, which demonstrates how one can persist the collapsing state in the grouping grid. Below I describe shortly the code. The demo uses one level of grouping to make the code more simple for understanding.

I added custom `collapsedGroups: {}` parameter to jqGrid. We will use the parameter to hold the list of collapsed groups. I used `collapsedGroups: { "test2": true }` in the demo to demonstrated that we can create the grid with some collapsed groups at the beginning. We don't use the value of the property of `collapsedGroups` object. Just the existence of the property `test2` for example means that the group with the value `test2` has collapsed state.

The demo uses `groupCollapse` property of `groupingView` defined as the callback function. The function tests whether the group is in the list of collapsed groups (has `collapsedGroups` property with some value)

```
groupingView: {
    groupField: ["name"],
    groupCollapse: function (options) {
        var collapsedGroups = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "collapsedGroups") || {};
        // options looks like { group: number, rowid: string }
        if (collapsedGroups.hasOwnProperty(options.group.value)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

We adjust additionally the properties of the custom `collapsedGroups` parameter after expanding/collapsing of the group. We use the following `onClickGroup` callback:

```
onClickGroup: function (hid, isCollapsed) {
    var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"),
        iGroup = $(this).jqGrid("getGroupHeaderIndex", hid),
        group = p.groupingView.groups[iGroup];

    if (p.collapsedGroups == null) {
        // be sure that the custom parameter is initialized as an empty object
        p.collapsedGroups = {};
    }
    if (isCollapsed) {
        // we place group.value in the p.collapsedGroups object as a property
        if (!p.collapsedGroups.hasOwnProperty(group.value)) {
            // create the property group.value in with some value
            p.collapsedGroups[group.value] = true;
        }
    } else if (p.collapsedGroups.hasOwnProperty(group.value)) {
        // remove group.value property from the p.collapsedGroups object
        delete p.collapsedGroups[group.value];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah now I have gone through the code and understood it. I kept the collapsedGroups parameter as empty `collapsedGroups:{}` and run the code. Now all the groups are expanded by default(==>(1)) and then if I click the collapse icon, the `onClickGroup` callback adds the collapsed groups to the parameter `collapsedGroups` . 
    ==>(1) This is were our requirement is slightly different, we need all of the groups to be  collapsed initially. so how shall I amend the code to make them all collapsed in the first load? this is where I need help!

Comment: @velavasimmanarumugan: It's very easy to implement. Look at the modified demo https://jsfiddle.net/92da8xhq/1/ where I removed `collapsedGroups: {}` and changed a little `groupCollapse` and `onClickGroup`.

Comment: does the free jqgrid support all the features (that are available before old jqGrid 4.7)? are the installation prorcesses are same? what are the difference between free jqgrid and Guriddo jqGrid JS? well, in short, my concern is, If I wish to switch to "free jqgrid" will I have to change my entire implementation? or how much compatible are these two?

Comment: @velavasimmanarumugan: Free jqGrid is compatible to jqGrid 4.7 and probably you will need just to change the URLs to `ui.jqgrid.min.css` and `jquery.jqgrid.min.js` and `grid.locale-XX.js` (or removing `grid.locale-en.js`, which is not needed for free jqGrid). [The link](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/compare/v4.7.0...master) shows that after 4.7 I made 1800 commits in the repository. I can't describe it here. Read [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html), [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and READMEs to every 21 versions published after v4.7.

Comment: Thanks a lot Oleg, It works!!! Now the state is retained while sorting. Thank you for your timely help. :)

Comment: now comes a problem, if there are 5 pages in the grid(pagination) and I go to third page and sort a column , the grid is redirected back to first page instead of staying in third page itself. is it possible to keep the page that we are previously in? But after that redirection if I navigate again to third page the state is retained!

Comment: @velavasimmanarumugan: I understand the problem, but I'm in a business trip now and work for one of my customer. I can examine the problem next week. You can post short description of the problem in https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues to be sure that I don't forget it.

Comment: I find a strange behaviour now. My grid many grouped rows. And previously I was using the "ui-icon-plusthick" and "ui-icon-minusthick" icons in the grouped rows. At that time this worked very well. Now, I am using "ui-icon-triangle-1-e" and "ui-icon-triangle-1-s" icons and a few groups expand and collapse well but a few not. When I debugged the issue I found that `group = p.groupingView.groups[iGroup];` gets undefined and I am seeing a TypeError in console. Error occurs on line `if (!p.collapsedGroups.hasOwnProperty(group.value)) {`. Help me on this.

Comment: @velavasimmanarumugan: Please post *the demo* with short test case, which reproduces the problem. To be able to help you I have to debug the problem too. Thus I have to have the demo, which reproduces the problem. I have my main job and m customers and I still try to help other with jqGrid in pauses in my main job. If you want to speed up your solution, then you should always provide the demo, which reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
groupingView: {
    groupCollapse: true,
            groupField: ["name"],
            plusicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-plus-square purple',
            minusicon: 'ace-icon fa fa-edit red'
}
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22476869)