# how to set jqgrid groping collapse based on columns?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

We are using JqGrid by using jquery and bootstrap.
In jqGrid Grouping collapse  I want to set specific columns to be collapse at run time.
this is my jqgrid settings

```
 grouping: true,
   groupingView: {
                    groupField: ['Country', 'Capital'],
                    groupColumnShow: [true, true],
                    groupText: ['<b>{0}</b>', '{0}'],
                    groupCollapse: true,
                    groupOrder: ['asc', 'asc'],
                    groupSummary: [true, false]
                },
```

so i want to something like this
 groupCollapse: ['Country'];
OR 
groupCollapse: ['Capital'];

How do i achieve this?

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used? Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <=4.7

Comment: Using free-jqGrid

Comment: look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47546617/315935) with [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/92da8xhq/), which shows how to use `groupCollapse`, defined as function. It allows to implement any custom rule  for collapsing/expanding the groups.