# How to insert custom rows in jqgrid and how to retain them on sorting columns?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

In jqgrid grouping concept I am trying to replicate the main header of the grid under each grouped row. The intention is if we have a lengthy table, in order to know what is the column name, we have to scroll up to the top of the table. Also, the same for sorting the columns. This seems tedious.

You can see what am I trying here [ https://jsfiddle.net/8L6xmwcc/2/ ]. I cloned the main header with event handlers and inserted it under each grouped item in the grid.

The problem is when I sort a column using this newly created header, sorting happens but this new header disappears from the table. Is it possible to retain it and do the sorting from this newly created header consistently?

Also, If I click the multiselect check box in the newly created header it selects all the rows under the table. But I want to discard that event how can I do it? Please help me on this.

```
loadComplete:function(){

   var grouped_header = $(".fa-plus-square-o").parents("tr[id^='grid1ghead']");

   $(".fa-plus-square-o").click(function(){
      if(!grouped_header.next().hasClass("ui-jqgrid-labels"))
      {
         var cloned_header = $(".ui-jqgrid-labels").clone(true);      
         cloned_header.insertAfter(grouped_header)          ;
      }
   });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is that everytime you click on sorting header, the content of the table reloads and `loadComplete` is called again. This renders the table again and effectively removes your custom headers.

what you need to do (apart from re-initializing the click handlers which you already do) is to re-append the headers to the sections that were clicked open previously. Also , when you clone, make sure you add :first selector only, or multiple instances will get copied to your clone.

This can be achieved with following code in `loadComplete` section:

```
    loadComplete:function(){
        console.log("loaded ....");
        /// add header to sections that are open
        $("tr[id^='grid1ghead']").each(function(){
          if($(this).next().css("display")!="none" && !$(this).next().hasClass("ui-jqgrid-labels")){
             var cloned_header = $(".ui-jqgrid-labels:first").clone(true);      
             $(this).after(cloned_header)    
          }
        })

        $(".fa-plus-square-o").click(function(){
          console.log("clicked it.");
          var grouped_header = $(this).parents("tr[id^='grid1ghead']");
          if(!grouped_header.next().hasClass("ui-jqgrid-labels"))
          {
             var cloned_header = $(".ui-jqgrid-labels:first").clone(true);      
             cloned_header.insertAfter(grouped_header)          ;
          }
        });

    },
```

For reference, your updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/8L6xmwcc/4/

Comment: Thanks a lot mike! that solved my problem and its a great help.

Comment: One more problem is, if we navigate to the second page and sort a column, the grid is reloaded and the we are redirected to first page, instead of staying in second page itself. Do you have an idea to solve this? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47546498/how-to-retain-expand-collapse-state-in-jqgrid-grouping/47546617?noredirect=1#comment82482887_47546617) at bottom, you can find my problem statement.

Comment: that seems to be a problem with jqgrid itself rather that the implementation from this question (you can reproduce that behaviour even without expanding the groups). Consider raising an issue with jqgrid if you can isolate it as their bug or post a separate question here on SO

Comment: from top of my head you can either write your own sorting that doesn't reload the table (thus resetting the page #) or you can hook into the page changing , setting the page number in a variable and then set the page when `loadComplete` is executed after you do the sorting

Comment: Yeah, I have raised a ticket in jqgrid github. But I am confused a bit, which one is professional? keeping the page state or redirecting to first page? depending on the column sorted data are going to shuffled. what would be the ideal one from user's perspective?