# Override grouping if non-grouped column contains a certain value

Tags: jqgrid

I'm grouping some data like this:

```
grouping:true,
groupingView: {
    groupField: ["IntakeDate"],
    groupColumnShow: [true],
    groupText: [
        "{0} Records: {1}"
    ],
    groupOrder: ["desc"],
    groupSummary: [true],
    groupCollapse: true,
    groupDataSorted: true
}
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to have the value of another column override the default collapse behavior. If any row in the group has a certain value in one of the other columns, then that group should not collapse.

**Update**
Sorry, I forgot to mention that this is the free version of jqGrid 4.6.0

Comment: Please include *always* the information about **the version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use), and **the fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). I develop "free jqGrid" fork and it allows to use callback function as the value of `groupCollapse`. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47546617/315935) for more details including the demo.

Comment: You should write short comment if you make changes of the text of your question. Only comment will produce the notification to people, who wrote comments you before. The version 4.6 is more as 4 years old and it isn't supported. The callback `onClickGroup` already exists in v4.6. Probably the usage of the callback is enough for your requirements. You can use retro version 4.6 or to upgrade to free jqGrid 4.15.3, which is upwards compatible to version 4.6.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for the heads up, and for all the hard work you've done. I didn't know that it had been forked. We're not going to update at this time since we won't have time to validate all 40 instances of jqGrid that this application has.

Comment: You can hold the old version of cause, but all required changes you will need to do yourself. You should understand another risk of holding of old version: **the web browsers will be updated every 1.5-2 months**. Look at [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10621951/315935), which describes the problem in jqGrid version <=4.3.2, with wrong calculating of column widths after updating Chrome to the version 19. The problem was fixed *only by changing of jqGrid code* (starting with version 4.3.3). The same or more hard problem could take place on every new update of Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: @Oleg Agreed. I meant, that I won't update right now because we have an imminent product release. Updating jqGrid is definitely on the backlog for the next one.